# How to set individual options in jquery

Tags: jquery, plugins, prototype, settings

I want to set individual options for my jquery plugin code. but i cannot set this individually. I tried with "$.each" function. I use jQuery with latest version

```js
$.fn.myMethods = function(option) {
  this.each(function() {
    const $item = $(this);
    $item.myMethods.option = $.extend({
      now: 1
    }, option);
  });
  return this;
}

$.fn.resultOfMyMethods = function() {
  this.each(function() {
    const $item = $(this);
    console.log($item.myMethods.option.now)
  });
  return this;
}

$('input').eq(0).myMethods({
  now: 123
});
$('input').eq(1).myMethods({
  now: 456
});

$('input').eq(0).resultOfMyMethods();
$('input').eq(1).resultOfMyMethods();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input/>
<input/>
```

expected results

```
123
456
```

actual results

```
456
456
```

Comment: The issue is that `$item.myMethods.option` is the same thing as `jQuery.fn.myMethods.options` which is shared by all jQuery instances.

Comment: In other words you are assigning property to the function object itself

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning a property to the `$.fn.myMethods` object, not to an instance.

You could use `data()` to store on individual elements.

```js
$.fn.myMethods = function(option) {

  const opts = $.extend({
    now: 1
  }, option);

  this.each(function() {
    const $item = $(this);
    $item.data('options', opts); // set on element
  });
  return this;
}

$.fn.resultOfMyMethods = function() {
  this.each(function() {
    const $item = $(this);
    console.log($item.data('options').now);// get from element
  });
  return this;
}

$('input').eq(0).myMethods({
  now: 123
});
$('input').eq(1).myMethods({
  now: 456
});

$('input').eq(0).resultOfMyMethods();// 123
$('input').eq(1).resultOfMyMethods();// 456
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input/>
<input/>
```